# "Key technical skills" section for a computer engineer: what can I put?

Tags: resume, skills

Currently, in my resume on "key technical skills", I have this list (organized in a 5x4 grid so to save space and not hide other relevant information):

> Android       CORBA       JUNIT           Servlets/JSP
>   Apache Tomcat       Eclipse         OpenFlow                   SDN
>   ASP/ASP.NET         Java                            PHP         SQL
>   C#      JavaScript      Python          Visual Studio
>   C/C++       JDBC            Qemu/KVM

Being a computer engineer I just listed known programming languages and technologies.
Is this section fine like that? Or I'd just need to further synthesize?

edit: 
I my studies section I listed as key modules things like "problem solving", "concurrent programming", "hardware programming" and so on.

Comment: Isn't Computer Engineering supposed to be hardware/very low-level software?

Comment: Not at all, we also do low level programming (forgot it in the list lol) but that really depends on your specialization and occupation. We work a lot at high levels as well: databases, networks, erp systems, software engineering...they are all things in which computer engineers excel.

Comment: I didn't mean that computer engineers can't do high-level software.  Anyone can do that stuff.  What I meant was that that's not what computer engineering is about.  If I were hiring for a Computer Engineer position (a real one, not a misnamed software dev position) I'd want to see the skills that set the profession apart.

Comment: so you mean the skills I put as key modules in my edit?

Comment: Computer Engineering is about hardware and embedded systems. Stuff like microcontrollers, eeprom, flash memory, soldering/connecting data wires from port to port, writing drivers for 2x16 LCD displays, and other fun stuff like that :) Suitable languages would be `C, VHDL, Assembly`

Comment: Ah ok...but anyway is it right to put known languages there? Yes I wanted to put VHDL and Assembly as well but they seemed too much specific and I'd just put them when submitting my CV to a specific company.

Comment: @jcm No, a computer engineer can have any focus from hardware to software or anywhere in between.  I've got a BS in CS, a MS in CE and am completely software focused.  CS vs. CE is typically more of a theory vs. practice difference in schools, and there isn't a difference in the workforce other than a CE should also understand hardware at slightly lower level.

Comment: Still...no one is actually answering me! Is it correct to put languages and technologies in this specific section?

Comment: Put languages and technologies that you know in this section. Don't list any you cannot answer in depth technical questions about in an interview.

Comment: If you need to debate the definition of Computer Engineering with the OP, does it really matter what he puts on his resume?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen er no its not computer engineering also covers CFD and Math modelling and HPC

Comment: Hello and welcome to The Workplace SE. The answer here really just depends on both your goals, as well as your educational background. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more details on what kinds of questions can fit here, as well as [ask], which may provide tips on how to possibly edit this post for a [reopen review](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen).

Answer (score 3):

There is no definition of what sections should be in a resume and what should be in those sections.

As a hiring manager, I expect your resume to tell me the story of who you are and what value you can provide to my organization.  I have seen many different styles and I'm sure that some of the styles I didn't care for, others would have really liked.

The most important thing is that you can convey to the reader why they should be giving you more time to talk to you about how good a fit you are for their job.

The one requirement i have:  don't make it a work of fiction.